# Visual Studio 2010 Silverlight Project Opening in Browser as file:// instead of localhost://

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, asp.net-development-serv

My main project I'm working on for some odd reason opens up in the browser as a file:// now instead of from localhost:// like it used to. I am unaware of any settings I changed to make it do this, and the Visual Studio ASP.NET Development Server still launches when I debug. All of my other projects still load from the development server when they are run.

Why would this one project suddenly decide that it wants to run as a regular file instead of from the Development Server? How can I fix it so that it loads from localhost as it should once more?

Thanks,

-Sootah

Comment: are you launching it from Expression Blend

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same issue when my startup project in Visual Studio was the Silverlight project. Make sure to set the startup project in your solution to the web application/site project.